# How do I display all of the property values from a record of an individual class into TableView

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a class of Animals that I need to build out with several dozen properties.  Currently, the animal list displays in a TableView and when touched, I want to go to a new ViewController that will have a TableView with all of the properties listed out (and available to be edited). It seems like I need to put all the properties into an array so that I can use that to feed the tableview.  But I don't know how to do that other than to manually go in and make something along the lines of :  animalArray.append("animal.animalsTypeName", "animal.animalsTypeNotes", "animal.animalsTypeID"....  etc for all of the properties that the class will ultimately have.

Is there some easier way to do that?

```
extension AnimalsType {

@nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<AnimalsType> {
    return NSFetchRequest<AnimalsType>(entityName: "AnimalsType")
}

@NSManaged public var animalsTypeName: String?
@NSManaged public var animalsTypeNotes: String?
@NSManaged public var animalsTypeID: UUID?
@NSManaged public var animalTypetoCore: NSSet?
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, you can put it as a function inside the AnimalType object itself, or modify it a little bit and put it outside the class and change the `reflecting: self` to reflect the instance of the AnimalsType object

```
public func getAsAnArray() -> [AnimalsType] {
     var resultArray        = [String]()
     let mirroredAnimalType = Mirror(reflecting: self)
     for (_, attr) in mirroredAnimalType.children.enumerated() {
        if let value = attr.value {
           if value.isEmpty {
                break
           }
              
           resultArray.append(value)
           // if you want a dictionary instead you can run
           // resultDictionary[attr.label!] = value
           // instead of resultArray.append(value)
        }
     }
     return resultArray
}
```

If you choose to put the function inside the class you can use it like this -

```
let array = animalsType.getAsAnArray()
```

Forgive me if I'm not breaking it down, I'll come back later and explain if needed when I have the time

Comment: Ah that makes very good sense!  I am only 2 months into learning so I appreciate the help here.  I'm using CoreData so I'm not sure if I can add that function inside the class itself?  So if not in the class, would I just add the function within the view controller of the view I'm planning to use it?

Comment: and just a couple questions here - 1) what is the purpose of using the mirror 2) I'm not familiar with the (_, att) portion of that statement above.  If I'm interpreting correctly, it is pulling all the attributes (properties?) of the animalType based upon the addition of specifying that I'm looking for the children of the class and to put them in an enumerated format?  I'm only familiar with the syntax of :  for attr in mirroredAnimalType.children.enumerated()

Comment: There isn't too much about Mirrors but you can find more in Apple's documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/mirror) 1) _A mirror describes the parts that make up a particular instance, such as the **instance’s stored properties**, collection or tuple elements, or its active enumeration case_. Which means, in simple words, that you can use mirror to access the Object's properties. 2) (_, att) is what you enumerate through, the first is the index which is _ because you don't need it in this instance, and att is the child itself, honestly I never tried it differently.

Comment: Excellent.  I've got that figured out now pretty good.  I tried using it with NSManaged objects and had to take a different route, but the mirror and reflection like you suggested put me exactly on the path I needed to figure that out!

Comment: The piece that I'm having trouble with now is that I have my property values and attribute names stored each in arrays like I want and those arrays are feeding.a tableview.  the table view is unlabeled on left and textfield on right that I want user to be able to edit.  based on the indexpath I can easily determine which field is being edited, but how do I set up the left hand part of the equation to say animal.name = textField.text. where name is the attribute name and will be changing depending on what row is clicked.  so ultimately I need it to be animal.(variable)